# Google BigQuery UDF Error

Tags: google-bigquery, udf

I am invoking a UDF from a select Query , however I see the following error at query time , does anyone know what the issue is  ? I have checked Accounting_Date it has valid date values of type 06/28/2015.

```
Error: Bad number for Accounting_Date
Error Location: User-defined function
Job ID: xxx-us-n-xxxx:bquijob_3c11b2e1_1538669f9fe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this error tells you that data type of output field (see emit portion) is not as it is declared in output schema section

Comment: Thanks , but now I get the following error for a different element which is being emitted as a String type but has a float type values. Error: Bad string for xxx_DR_Amt_GC

Comment: you might want to use parseFloat() or toString() depends which direction you need to transform your value

Comment: I am taking it in as a string and emitting as a string , to I still need to explicitly use parseFloat()

Comment: based on your comment - looks like you need to use toString() as your valule is float but expected output is string. but i can be wrong as i am quite blind here. if still issue - you might want to show some respective code lines

Answer (score 0):

Is this a field with TIMESTAMP type? If so, it will appear as a JS Date object in the JS UDF.